# How to merge AndroidManifest.xml in bazel

Tags: bazel

My android project contains some aar modules, which have their own AndroidManifest.xml. What should I do to have the aar's manifest to be merged into the final AndroidManifest.xml?

Thanks very much for any help!

My `android_binary` rule:

```
android_binary(
    name="apk",
    custom_package = "com.xtbc",
    manifest_merger = "android",
    manifest = "AndroidManifest.xml",
    resource_files = glob(["res/**"], exclude=["res/.DS_Store"]),
    assets = glob(["assets/**"], exclude=["assets/.DS_Store"]),
    assets_dir = "assets",
    multidex = "manual_main_dex",
    main_dex_list = "mainDexList.txt",
    dexopts = [
        "--force-jumbo"
    ],
    deps = [
        ":lib",
        ":base_lib",
        ":jni"
    ]
)
```

The `:base_lib` is a module (ie, an `android_library` rule):

```
android_library(
    name = "base_lib",
    srcs = glob(["base/src/**/*.java"]),
    custom_package = "com.xtbc.base",
    manifest = "base/AndroidManifest.xml",
    resource_files = glob(["base/res/**"], exclude=["base/res/.DS_Store"]),
    assets = glob(["base/assets/**"], exclude=["base/assets/.DS_Store"]),
    assets_dir = "base/assets",
    deps = [
        "@androidsdk//com.android.support:support-annotations-23.0.1"
    ]
)
```

It has its own `base/AndoridManifest.xml`, what I want is that the `:base_lib`'s AndroidManifest.xml will be merged into the final AndroidManifest.xml(ie, the `:apk`'s AndroidManifest.xml).

Comment: Does [`aar_import`](https://bazel.build/versions/master/docs/be/android.html#aar_import) help?

Comment: You may also be interested in [`android_binary.manifest_merger`](https://bazel.build/versions/master/docs/be/android.html#android_binary.manifest_merger).

Comment: Thanks very much @Laszlo, I added the `manifest_merger = "android"` to my `android_binary` rule, but the module's manifest seems still didn't contained in the final AndroidManifest. I'm putting the module to the `android_binary`'s `deps`, am I wrong?

Comment: You're welcome! Did I answer your question? I'm not sure :)

Comment: Still have some problem like above

Comment: Could you say more about what you tried (maybe show us the rules you wrote), what bazel does, and what you think it should be doing instead?

Comment: OK @Laszlo, I have updated the question to the detail. Thanks very much!

Comment: Thanks! How about [`android_library.exports_manifest`](https://bazel.build/versions/master/docs/be/android.html#android_library.exports_manifest), does that help?

Comment: OK, thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not have enough stackoverflow reputation to respond to the comment chain, but it sounds like what you are after is the `exports_manifest` attribute of `android_library`.

The documentation at https://bazel.build/versions/master/docs/be/android.html#android_library.exports_manifest says that the default is 1, however, that documentation is based on source code changes that have not made it into a Bazel release yet. For now you will need to add `exports_manifest = 1` onto your `android_library`. In the next Bazel release, this will no longer be necessary.

Also, regarding "AAR modules": If these are prebuilt .aar files, you will want to use the aar_import rule. It does not have an exports_manifest attribute, because it will always export by default. If these are Gradle Android library modules, then you can just use the android_library rule. If you were referring to the support libraries, @androidsdk//com.android.support:support-annotations-23.0.1 is actually a JAR, not an AAR.